# Java GUI libraries

Tags: java, user-interface

I understand this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138722/which-gui-library-is-the-best-in-java), but that was back in 2008, and things have changed. I tried looking for Swing, but the JFC is now outdated, and I can't seem to find Swing anywhere else.

I'd like to know what the best up-to-date java GUI libraries are.

Comment: What makes you think "the JFC is now outdated"?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse and NetBeans provide their own libraries.

Comment: When I first got into all of this, I wasn't aware Eclipse came with the JFC, so please don't think I'm an idiot. ;P Anyways, the reason why I thought the JFC was outdated was because whenever I tried to download the Java IDE after googling JFC, I would get these weird "end of life" messages.

Comment: I fear you are still confused. Eclipse does not come with the JFC; the JFC is part of the JDK. Also, there's no such thing as "the Java IDE" - there are several IDEs. And I've no idea which "end of life" messages you got...

Comment: Sorry, I WAS confused. I had IDE and SDK confused. This is the pageI tried to download the JFC from: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/download-103.html Trying to download the Java 2 SDK also gives an EOL

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the question you link to ( [Which GUI Library is the best in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138722/which-gui-library-is-the-best-in-java)
), the answers there are still relevant.

Short version:

There are two serious contenders for a GUI: [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) and [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit).

Swing is more mature (arguably), is part of the standard JDK (no deployment issues), very flexible and well-documented.

SWT makes it easier to behave like a native application across different OSes (but this also means significantly more portability issues). It also reportedly performs better in some scenarios (but this depends very much on what you do).

Some other considerations:

I'd seriouly consider creating a web app when making a new app nowadays. In that case, SWT scores an extra point, because it has [Eclipse RAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_AJAX_Platform) which (more or less) lets you convert a desktop client into a web client by just recompiling against different libraries, because it uses the same API as SWT.

Also, you might consider building atop a client framework, instead of writing from scratch. In that case, if you use Eclipse as your framework, you'll have to use SWT. Or use Netbeans, which is based on Swing...

Answer (score 3):

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) has been good to me. It provides a native look-and-feel by using native controls when available.

You can optionally use it and [JFace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace) in the [Eclipse Rich-Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform), which provides a framework for applications built atop a community of plug-ins. It has a high learning curve, but provides a mature, powerful framework that you don't have to build.