# How to create a GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have used Java for some time, but I have never created a GUI - always CLI. How does one create a GUI in Java? Can you suggest a good tutorial/reference?

I'm looking to create a simple GUI that has two long text areas and some buttons.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: @Flynn1179 what google considers as popular websites for GUI does not give me the professional opinion I am looking for in SO.

Comment: Three out of four answers and a comment agree with google, as do I.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579867/java-gui-libraries/4579902#4579902 .

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Foo{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("A JFrame");
    f.setSize(250, 250);
    f.setLocation(300,200);
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
    f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);
    final JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textArea.append("Button was clicked\n");

        }
    });

    f.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

Comment: event can be replaced with a lambda expression: button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        textArea.append("Button was clicked\n");
            });  -  this example is worth a thousand words...

Comment: I just started learning java and swing, why you didn't manipulate the GUI in the Event Dispatch Thread using `invokeLater()` method here ? They say this is a must because Swing is not thread-safe ?

Answer (score 8):

Read about [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) on Oracle Tutorial's pages.

Comment: Plz no. It's 2017 there is no reason to use Swing over Javafx/others

Answer (score 2):

There is:

- [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)
- [Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Well what you have to do is create your text/code thin (Note Pad++ or Notepad)  and remember the name.

Then open it an type

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

This basically tells java to get `java.awt` and `javax.swing` from its various code libraries that came with java when you downloaded it (Understandable as this is language made to help developers).

You then need to make your function that will have everything from the size, text inside it, color ect. REMEBER, we are not coding the gui here as that was already done when we imported  import `java.awt.*;` and   `javax.swing.*`;.

When I put `public class work` ,Work in the name of my file (if it was called code it would be `public class code`.

```
public class work {

private static void createWindow() {

 //Create and set up the window
 JFrame frame = new JFrame ("simple GUI");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Im cool" ,SwingConstants.CENTER); 
 textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
 frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 //Display the window
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

Remember you have not called the function anywhere, its basically waiting there until it is called.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

This tells the computer that what ever comes next, you do when i run the program.

So inside that you need to put

```
createWindow();
```

As this is what you called your function above and it is calling the function, you do not need to call this function as it does it when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

You have different possibilities here, but I'd recommend using Swing with an IDE such as Netbeans, which provides a very good WYSIWYG editor (called Matisse).

Netbeans also has project templates that you can use to quickly get started.

Finally, as others pointed out, make sure to do your homework and read some beginner Swing tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a JFrame is not all as hard as people think, all you need is a definition class and a   GUI Class. It's one of the simplest things in Java

Definition Class:

```
public class GetMyJavaWindow {
public static void main (String args[]) {
new JavaWindow();
}
}
```

JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaWindow { // Class name must match what it says in the def. class
public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // Needed for the JFrame to work.

public JavaWindow() { // Must match class name

this.setVisible(true); // Required
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Required
this.setSize(800,600); // this.setSize (x,y);

}
}
```

If you need any more GUI help, come to me.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ (Tutorials from Oracle)
http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial

Search for "Java Swing tutorials" :)